# gl_FragColor and glReadPixels

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am still trying to read pixels from fragment shader and I have some questions.
I know that gl_FragColor returns with vec4 meaning RGBA, 4 channels.
After that, I am using glReadPixels to read FBO and write it in data

```
GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[640*480*4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, 640,480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

This works fine but it really has speed issue. Instead of this, I want to just read RGB so ignore alpha channels. I tried:

```
GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[640*480*3];
glReadPixels(0, 0, 640,480, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

instead and this didn't work though. I guess it's because gl_FragColor returns 4 channels and maybe I should do something before this? Actually, since my returned image (gl_FragColor) is grayscale, I did something like

```
float gray = 0.5 //or some other values
gl_FragColor = vec4(gray,gray,gray,1.0);
```

So is there any efficient way to use glReadPixels instead of using the first 4 channels method? Any suggestion? By the way, this is on opengl es 2.0 code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OpenGL ES 2.0 spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) says that there are two valid forms of the call:

```
glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

or

```
GLint format, type;
glGetIntegerv(IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &format);
glGetIntegerv(IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, &type);
glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, format, type, pixels);
```

The possible combinations for `format` and `type` are (pic taken from the spec):

[image: table]

And the implementation will decide which is available to you.

However, it's likely that if you create a rendering surface of an appropriate format, then that will be the format you'll obtain here. See if you can modify your code to obtain a RGB framebuffer (i.e. with 0 bits for alpha channel). Or perhaps you might want to create an offscreen framebuffer object for that purpose?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will definitely try it soon! But can you give me more idea or description about offscreen framebuffer? I am a little bit new to graphics so I am not familiar with terms. Perhaps link for tutorial? Thanks again!

Comment: A Frame Buffer Object (FBO) is basically a secondary render target which you create by yourself. It may contain a colour buffer, depth buffer, alpha buffer or anything. You can then draw to it (instead of to the "screen", i.e. the primary frame buffer) and use the results somehow, for example as a texture for effects, or to read back the pixels (in your case).

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html looks like a nice practical tutorial with example code (for OpenGL though; it should be +- the same in ES 2). Also have a read at the specs (linked earlier; chapter 4.4.3).